# How many ways to stack $n$ boxes of 4 colours so that no $2$ blue boxes are consecutive.

Tags: proof-verification, recurrence-relations

Let $X_n$ denote the number of ways to stack red, white and blue and green boxes, find the ways to count the ways of stacking n boxes, with no consecutive blue boxes.

**My attempt:**

Let $X^R_n$ denote the number of ways of stacking n boxes with no consecutive blues, that have a red on top. Same for $X^W_n, X^B_n, X^G_n$.

Thus $X_n=X^R_n+X^W_n+X^B_n+ X^G_n$

Then $X^R_n=X_{n-1}$ as you have a n-string word with a defined last letter.
With the same logic:

$X^R_n=X^W_n=X^G_n=X_{n-1}$.

For $X^B_n$ we have that the last character is B but the character before that can be only W, G or R so we get:

$X^B_n=X^R_{n-1}+X^W_{n-1}+ X^G_{n-1}=3X_{n-2}$

$$
\therefore X_n=3X_{n-1}+3X_{n-2}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good. You have an unlimited supply of boxes of each colour by the look of it.

Comment: Yep! Only (somewhat trivial thing) that I'd add: as you have a recurrence relation with a term $X_{n-2}$, you'll want to put two initial conditions in, i.e. $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add that, I need to solve it also, but it's kind of a pain in the butt with the numbers I got. The initial conditions should be $X_1=4, X_2=15$, right?

Comment: The initial conditions are right. I might have used $X_0=1$, $X_1=4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to distinguish between blue and nonblue.

An admissible stack $S$ of height $n$ has a nonblue box on top or a blue box. In the first case $S'=S\setminus{\rm top\ box}$ is an admissible stack of height $n-1$, and in the second case $S''$ is an admissible stack of height $n-2$, and the $(n-1)^{\rm st}$ box is nonblue. It follows that
$$X_n=3X_{n-1}+3X_{n-2}\ .$$
Furthermore one has $X_1=4$, $X_2=4^2-1=15$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you have four sets of $n$ boxes in the colours red white blue and green.
You can stack the red white and green boxes in $$\frac {(3n)!}{(n!)^3}$$ ways, and the remaining $n$ blue boxes can be inserted individually into the $(3n+1)$ gaps between these boxes (including the beginning and end) in $$\frac {(3n+1)!}{(2n+1)!n!}$$ ways. Then you multiply these together